# Probability that number begins with one

Tags: probability, random

I have three very similar algorithms generating very different results. In all of them I'm calculating distribution of first number of random number.

1. [First algorithm](http://ideone.com/Lh3doc) Here I'm generating random numbers from set $\{ 1, \ldots, 999999 \}$. Result is like uniform distribution.
2. [Second algorithm](http://ideone.com/2KIf0T) There are random numbers chosen from set $\{ l, \ldots, u \}$ where $l$ and $u$ are random numbers for every random number generated. Result is like normal distribution.
3. [Third algorithm](http://ideone.com/Q39FA5) In this algorithm I'm generating random numbers from set $\{ 1, \ldots, u \}$ for some fixed $u$. Result is like exponential distribution.

Why those weird things happen?

Comment: This has to do with how you are selecting your numbers. From 1 to 99...9, there are an equal amount of numbers with different first digits. A similar effect occurs with the other selections but I can't comment on why the specific distributions work before I look into it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of [Benford's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law).  The results of your first algorithm should not be surprising, as $\frac 19$ of the numbers have each leading digit.  You can prove this by counting them in each decade.  The other extreme would be to select a number at random from the set $\{1,\dots,199999\}$.  Now a little over half the numbers have leading digit $1$.  If you draw numbers from $[1,k]$, the density of leading $1$'s oscillates between (about) $\frac 59$ and $\frac 19$.  The density of leading $9$'s oscillates between $\frac 1{18}$ and $\frac 19$.